# OpenAPI Schema Validatornot validating required properties correctly

Tags: python-3.x, openapi

**Versions**

- Python v3.9.16
- openapi-schema-validator v0.4.4
- pytest v7.3.1

**Setup**

`schema.json`

```json
{
    "openapi": "3.0.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "title": "CustomObject"
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "CustomObject": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "testprop": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": ["testprop"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a test that is supposed to verify a failure condition by not supplying the required property:

```py
def test_invalid_data():
    cur_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    defintion = os.path.join(cur_dir, 'schema.json')
    with open(defintion, 'r') as file:
        schema = json.load(file)

    valid_data = {}
    json_data = json.dumps(valid_data)

    with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
        validate(json.loads(json_data), schema)
```

However, when this executes it throws the following error:

> ```
>     with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
>       validate(json.loads(json_data), schema)
> ```
>
> E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError'>

**Constraints**

The OpenAPI Spec schema is downloaded from the AWS Schema Registry, so I can't change it.  I'm mentioning this because, whilst the structure of the document is valid (according to the OpenAPI online validator), it differs slightly from the example in the [openapi-schema-validator](https://github.com/python-openapi/openapi-schema-validator#usage) docs.

I've tried running this test without trying to catch the exception and that test passes, which it shouldn't.

**Question**

Can you explain to me why this isn't throwing the error I expect?